# Why isn't my Router redirecting?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My Angular project structure is as follows:
Index.html contains `<app-root></app-root>`, which is my app.component.
My App Component has the following structure:

```
<md-toolbar>
  <ng-template #notLoggedIn>
    <a md-icon-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="topnavUserMenu">
      <md-icon>person_add</md-icon>
    </a>
    <md-menu #topnavUserMenu="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>
        <md-icon>fingerprint</md-icon>
        <span><a [routerLink]="['/login']" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a></span></button>
      <button md-menu-item>
        <md-icon>mode_edit</md-icon>
        <span><a [routerLink]="['/signup']">Register</a></span></button>
    </md-menu>
  </ng-template>
</md-toolbar>
<md-sidenav-container>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

Basically, the app.component is persistent across the app, and all content is rendered through the `router-outlet`. If the user selects "Login" from the toolbar menu, the desired behavior is for the app to redirect to the URL, however, when the user clicks the link, nothing happens.

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

NOTE: I am aware I could do this pragmatically by adding a navigate function to my app.component and binding it to the button's click, for example:

```
test() {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

I am more interested in why it doesn't work with HTML directives, but it works flawlessly with JS.

Comment: try this: <a routerLink="/login">Go to login</a>

Comment: have you defined all your routes in a ts file?

Comment: @Avi that didn't work...

Comment: @jmw5598 yes of course, everything is in app.routes.ts

Comment: Is it legal to have an anchor tag nested inside a button tag?

Comment: @birwin you are correct! I updated my code and it worked like magic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are a novice and would find this information useful, @birwin's claim is correct - an anchor tag is illegal in a button. You need to change:

```
<button md-menu-item>
        <md-icon>mode_edit</md-icon>
        <span><a [routerLink]="['/signup']">Register</a></span>
</button>
```

to:

```
<button md-menu-item [routerLink]="['/signup']">
        <md-icon>mode_edit</md-icon>
        <span>Register</span>
</button>
```